# Search input area autogrow - how?

Tags: jquery, javascript, search

I've tried for many hours to style my searchform. I managed to get it all done after some research. I even managed to get the text highlighted when on focus using javascript (no idea if there's a non-javascript solution as well).
anyways, I've been googling around and trying out all sorts of things (e.g. playing around with the width when "onfocus" in my style.css) - nothing worked.
I want a width autogrow for my searchform like in the [Twenty Eleven Theme](http://wp-themes.com/twentyeleven/?TB_iframe=true&width=1341&height=542).
Basically what I want is when you click on the input area the it will get a bit wider.

What I could find was this [plugin](http://file:///C:/Users/Arashizakura/Desktop/search-autogrow-boxtuffs.com/search-autogrow-boxtuffs.com/search-autogrow-boxtuffs.com/index.html) which uses jquery. I don't know how to implement it, though. 
Is using jquery the only option I have? Can I get this effect via a different method?

I really tried a lot and searched around for hours, but couldn't find an answer, so I'd be happy for any kind of advice you can give me :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they're using [CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp).

```
<style type="text/css">
#s {
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-transition-property: width, background;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -moz-transition-property: width, background;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -o-transition-property: width, background;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
    width: 72px;
}
#s:focus {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 196px;
}
</style>

<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search">
```

Comment: Hey there :) Wow, so it's done with CSS after all. I'm glad to hear that. I copied the code above into the template, I also put the CSS additinally into the style.css of my theme. It doesn't take effect. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so much for helping me! :)

Comment: make sure you have the same id `s` on your search field and that there aren't other more specific css rules overriding it. a good tool for this stuff is chrome or safari's [web inspector](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector). right-click on any element and select 'inspect element' and you'll see all of the css rules being applied.

Comment: I got it now, but it's messing up my searchbar. The magnifying glass graphic is suddenly in the middle of the search field. Very strange. Guess I have to play around with it a little. And thank you for the tip. I'm using Firefox's Firebug :)

Answer (score 0):

great!

edit the css as follow:

```
#q {
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-transition-property: width, background;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -moz-transition-property: width, background;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -o-transition-property: width, background;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
/* edit and add from here */
    width: 16px;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    background: #333333 url(/img/search.png) no-repeat;
}
#q:hover { cursor: pointer; } /* added line */
#q:focus {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 196px;
/* edit from here */
    color: #333333;
    background-image: none;
}
```

and replace the icon url with an icon of your choice like, for example:
http://glyphicons.com/ and you can get the same functionality everywhere!

And with this jQuery plugin ( http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/live-search/#jquery-plugin-example ) you can add interactive search :D

Comment: I fail to see what is added here that Milo didn't say 18 months ago. Please elaborate on how this adds substance to this question.

Comment: @johannes it adds a search button image just like in wordpress. when you click on the button it disappear and the input search field is shown